# Why doesn't npm start or npm install work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm, expo

I'm just getting started with react/firebase/expo so I'm really baffled on this one.

I'm not even sure how to explain what's happening, but basically if I try to run "npm install", I get the following output on the console:

```
E:\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project p 
roperty pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\User\source\repos\projeto\projeto\Moosic\node_modules\grpc\build\z.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `E:\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
```

Whole output is here: https://pastebin.com/85kSH3qt

If I run npm start, EXPO tells me

> ERROR warn Package firebase has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'firebase\package.json'
> Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\User\source\repos\projeto\projeto\Moosic\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\resolveNodeModuleDir.js
> - C:\Users\User\source\repos\projeto\projeto\Moosic\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\releaseChecker\index.js
> - C:\Users\User\source\repos\projeto\projeto\Moosic\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\start\runServer.js
> - C:\Users\User\source\repos\projeto\projeto\Moosic\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\start\start.js
> - C:\Users\User\source\repos\projeto\projeto\Moosic\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
> - C:\Users\User\source\repos\projeto\projeto\Moosic\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
> - C:\Users\User\source\repos\projeto\projeto\Moosic\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cli.js

I really have no clue what's happening. I'm trying to work on a shared repo and everyone else is managing to work just fine. I don't know if this is from a single cause, two different causes, or what is happening. Any help is appreciated, as I've been fighting this problem for the last day with no success.

Comment: `Cannot find module 'firebase\package.json'` did you add in the dependencies for Firebase?

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --global windows-build-tools` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools)

Comment: @yudhiesh I have  "firebase": "7.9.0","firebase-admin": "^9.4.1" and "firebase-functions": "^3.12.0" on the dependencies section of package.json, yes

Comment: @Matt I have. It runs without problems but when I do npm install/npm start I get the same problems

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to find where those `windows-build-tools` are installed and put them in your PATH before the `E:\Visual Studio\MSBuild` directory

Comment: @Matt any advice on how to do that? E:\Visual Studio\MSBuild doesn't show up on any system variables

Comment: Not sure in that case, maybe look into how node finds the build tools path? Might be a wild goose chase though, I'm not 100% sure that the tools are the problem

Comment: Did you tried what is suggested as solution beside the error in the logs? see `error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project p ` probably you are not setting the sdk path in the environment variable correctly.

Comment: @Mostav I can't find that version anywhere to download. Also, it doesn't show up on the path https://pasteboard.co/JDPDXia.png (sorry it's not in english). Any tips?

Comment: Refer to the official doc here for windows: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup